# Change of variables, why does integral disappear?

Tags: integration, substitution

In a [PDF about Gaussian-Stochastic models for spectral diffusion](http://home.uchicago.edu/~tokmakoff/TDQMS/Notes/7.2.%20Stochastic%20Model%203-08.pdf), there is a simplification made by change of variable between equations 7.21 and 7.22 that I just can't seem to make.

Writing it here,

$$\tfrac{1}{2}\int^t_0 d\tau' \int^t_0 d\tau'' \langle d\omega(\tau' - \tau'') d\omega(0) \rangle ~~~~~~~~~~~~7.21$$

Substitute in $\tau = \tau' - \tau''$

$$ \int^t_0 d\tau  (t - \tau) \langle d\omega(\tau) d\omega(0) \rangle ~~~~~~~~~~~~7.22$$

How did it happen? Please show me the intermediate steps.

---

My attempt

$$\tfrac{1}{2}\int^t_0 d\tau' \int^t_0 d\tau'' \langle d\omega(\tau' - \tau'') d\omega(0) \rangle $$
$$d\tau = d\tau' - d\tau''$$
$$\int^t_0  d\tau' \int^t_0 (d\tau' - d\tau) \langle \delta \omega( \tau )\delta \omega(0) \rangle $$
$$\int^t_0  d\tau' \int^t_0 d\tau' \langle \delta \omega ( \tau )\delta \omega(0) \rangle   - \int^t_0  d\tau' \int^t_0  d\tau \langle \delta \omega( \tau )\delta \omega(0) \rangle $$
$$ t^2\langle \delta \omega ( \tau )\delta \omega (0) \rangle   - \int^t_0  d\tau' \int^t_0  d\tau \langle \delta \omega ( \tau )\delta \omega (0) \rangle$$
It seems like I am making some obvious mistake, maybe with $d\tau = d\tau' - d\tau''$?

Comment: When you are substituting $\tau''$ with $\tau$, you only consider the inner integral for which $\tau'$ is a constant. So that gives us $d \tau = - d\tau''$. Now for a given $\tau'$ you will also have to change the limits. Once you do that and evaluate, you will get the required expression.